# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" com array

Tags: php, mysql

pessoal estou com um problema
fica aparecendo esse erro 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','daniel')' at line 1

```
<?php

$codigo = array_filter($_POST['codigo']);

foreach ($codigo as $key => $value) {
    $codigo = $value;
 $nome_pedido = $_POST["nome"][0];
    $pedido = $_POST["pedido"][$key];

echo $codigo."<br>";
    echo $nome_pedido."<br>";
    echo $pedido."<br>";



    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES";
    $sql .="(NULL,'$codigo',$nome_pedido','$pedido')";
     var_dump($sql);


    if ($conn1 ->query($sql) === true){

echo "    <div id=\"sucess-forn\" class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\" style=\"position: absolute; \n";
echo "top: 0; \n";
echo "left: 0; \n";
echo "z-index: 10; \n";
echo "padding:5px; \n";
echo "width:99%;\n";
echo " position: fixed; \">\n";
echo "<a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" href=\"#\">×</a>";

echo "        <center><h1 class=\"alert-heading\">Fornecedor cadastrado com sucesso!</h1></center>\n";
echo "</div>\n";


    } else {
        echo "erro:". $sql . "<br>" . $conn1->error;
    }

}


$conn1->close();






?>
```

alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema e me exlicar o que esta acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, creio que seja tudo questão da má formatação de seu código, vi alguns erros e vou lhe mandar aqui. Creio que o maior problema estava em sua variavel `$sql` pois sua query não estava reconhecendo os valores por estar separada em 2 partes, o que não é necessario, pode se colocar em apenas 1 linha, ainda mais pelo tamanho desta. Teste por ai para ver se resolverá seu problema, não consegui testar por aqui pois não tenho acesso ao seu código HTML e afins.

```
<?php

$codigo = array_filter($_POST['codigo']);

foreach ($codigo as $key => $value) {
    $codigo = $value;
    $nome_pedido = $_POST["nome"][0];
    $pedido = $_POST["pedido"][$key];

    echo $codigo."<br>";
    echo $nome_pedido."<br>";
    echo $pedido."<br>";



    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES (NULL, '$codigo', '$nome_pedido', '$pedido')";
    var_dump($sql);


    if ($conn1->query($sql) === true) {
        echo "    <div id=\"sucess-forn\" class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\" style=\"position: absolute; \n";
        echo "top: 0; \n";
        echo "left: 0; \n";
        echo "z-index: 10; \n";
        echo "padding:5px; \n";
        echo "width:99%;\n";
        echo " position: fixed; \">\n";
        echo "<a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" href=\"#\">×</a>";

        echo "        <center><h1 class=\"alert-heading\">Fornecedor cadastrado com sucesso!</h1></center>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
    } else {
        echo "erro:". $sql . "<br>" . $conn1->error;
    }
}

$conn1->close();
?>
```

Comment: resolveu o problema obrigado, mas me explique era so ma questão de ma formatação ou tinha algum erro a mais?

Comment: Então cara, em minha IDE quando joguei o seu código já apareceu que a partir do ```NULL```de sua ```$sql``` ele já não estava reconhecendo, até pq tbm em sua variavel ```$nome_pedido``` estava faltando uma ```'``` antes desta. Você pode concatenar a query mas não precisa declarar ela 2 vezes e não precisa usar o ```.=```, pode apenas pular a linha e usar o ```.```. Na linha ```$conn1->query($sql``` estava com o ```->``` separado, não sei se impactou em algo, mas por boas práticas é bom deixar na sintaxe correta. Se possivel, marca a resposta como correta e clique na seta para cima rs.

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado de verdade estava ficando louco

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando uma aspa simples na sua variável $nome_pedido do seu sql:

```
$sql .="(NULL,'$codigo','$nome_pedido','$pedido')";
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: vlw meu amigo ajudou bastante

Comment: Essa é a resposta correta.